# Pressure Tank not holding water

Tags: well

Just put in new submersible well pump, pressure tank will fill and once full well pump shuts off all the water runs out of the tank. Everything is turned off in the house, why is water rushing out of the pressure tank?  It’s a well-trol. Also the air pressure gauge below the pressure switch isn't working does this cause any issues as well?

Comment: You mean the water runs out when the pump is running? Or after it shuts off?  If the after it shuts off then it sounds like you have a bad or missing check valve.  Perhaps the old pump had it built in and the new requires stand-alone?  If it’s running out while the pumps still running you must a a leak somewhere.

Comment: It's after the pump shuts off, we put a new pump in its a Hallmark submersible pump. If it doesn't have one, paperwork doesn't say if it has one or not do you install somewhere up top? Also if it does have one in the pump is it possible being a new pump its not working? Sorry for so many questions

Comment: The common problem if the water runs back out (to the well) when the pump shuts off is that the “check valve” (one direction flow valve) is missing or stuck.  Sorry I don’t know if your old pump or new has one built in.  Sometimes they are part of the pump, sometimes installed as a separate item.

Comment: I looked up the pump and it says it has one installed inside the pump, instead of having to pull the pump again could we install one outside of it?

Answer (score 1):

With a new pump it should be good but they ( the check valve) do get stuck sometimes. When this happens I will add a check valve just prior to the tank. Adding a valve is easier than pulling the pump. I did have a line from the pump to the tank that cracked, I tried the check valve and it did work for a while but the crack got so bad it would not pump more than 20 psi, at that point we pulled the pump and found the crack and replaced the line, hope that helps.

Comment: Ok in speaking with ex, he said when the pump is first turned on it fills up the tank and pressure switch kicks off the water runs out. then the pump kicks back on and just keeps running and only fills the tank 1/2 full and keeps running nonstop. He has to manually click off the pressure switch. Sorry I'm trying to get all the facts

Comment: It sounds like the check valve may be working but the line to the pressure tank from the pump may be opening this is close to what I ended up trying to figure out my well tester suggested this after the problem got worse to pull the pump and check the line and that's when we found the problem once the crack was enough to limit the pressure to 20 or so  when the pressure switch was sat for 50/60